# SharePoint form library not opening in browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

InfoPath form library not opening in browser. When i click new document it opening in browser and when I create item, then try to open the same item, it is not opening instead downloading. I want it to open in browser, how to achieve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Advance setting** of the Library in Library Settings page and check for option Open document in browser. Select Open in Browser and click ok
 You should be able to open in browser then.

Comment: I tired but no luck!

Comment: Did you create a browser enabled form? Please go through the link if you have not already gone through http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2014/infopath-forms-not-opening-browser-sharepoint.htm